# add amount on tuesday as tuesday +monday

Tags: mysql, sql, date, reportbuilder

Date -      amount-    name of date

2017-09-05  364100.00   Tuesday
2017-09-11  189700.00   Monday

Tuesday should have value as 364100+189700

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your google search string is `MySQL date functions`.

Comment: Gordon : Date Collateral   Origination
8/1/2017 $849,099.92   $131,900.00
8/2/2017 $849,099.92   $152,100.00
8/3/2017 $849,099.92   $233,900.00
8/4/2017 $849,099.92   $407,200.00
8/7/2017 $849,099.92   $154,700.00                                                                       origination data should:
• On a Monday, pull Monday loans only.
• On a Tuesday, pull Monday and Tuesday loans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM origination_table
WHERE  WEEKDAY(origination_date) <= WEEKDAY(NOW())
   AND WEEKDAY(origination_date) > WEEKDAY(NOW())-2
   AND .... others like origination_date>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 day)
```